# Excel nested formula with different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula that returns data from a different sheet in the same workbook.  I currently have a nested formula of 2 arguments and another single argument and am wanting to combine them.  As is, they are working fine.

Book 1 is my source report.  Book 2 is the report I'm creating with these formulas.

Book 1 column B has (in this example) the first name and the total.  Book 1 column C has the last names.  The current formulas return the greyed out names in Column A as long as the text in Book 1 column B <> "Total."  What I'm needing to do is move those greyed names into the same column as the last names.  So I need to somehow combine the 2 formulas.  Basically what I'm wanting to say in $B is:

If Book 1 B1 is not blank but not "Total" then return B1 -OR- if Book 1 C1 is not blank then return C1.  If Book 1 B1 = "Total" then B1 is blank.

Nesting this nested and single formula creates too many arguments.  I also tried:

```
=IF(OR(Book 1!C3)<>"",Book 1!C3,""),IF(AND((Book 1!B3)<>"",LEFT(Book 1!B3,5)<>"Total"),Book 1!B3,""))
```

(If C isn't blank, return that or if B isn't blank but isn't "Total", return that.  Else leave blank)
Excel says there's a problem with the formula.  I don't fully disagree :)

I am probably way over thinking this.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the following formula for Column B of Book 2.

```
=IF(B6<>"Total",IF(B6<>"",B6,C6),"")
```

Drag it down to fill the other cells.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Insert slow clap.  Thank you!

Comment: @GMcMahon Good that it worked for you. Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how to navigate say thank you on this site.